# Can a the block code from a trigger call the same trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, triggers

I have this trigger sql code

```
create trigger fill_table_number on NUMBER after insert
as begin

if((select count(*) from NUMBER)<10)
  begin

    insert into NUMBER select count(*)+1 from NUMBER

  end

end
```

And then I execute this code

```
insert into NUMBER values(1)
```

The result of this is a table with two rows, row one=1,row two=2,
when I excpected ten rows 1,2,4,5,6,..,10.

Here's the question, on sql the trigger is executed after the first row is inserted, but the insert inside doesn't not call one more time the trigger.

Why this happen?, is this a restriction of sql? does it happen on mysql,oracle or other database? or do I miss some concept?

Comment: I got it, the trigger is already in use, thanks!

Comment: You should not use reserved words (NUMBER) for table or column names.

Comment: I actually used NUMERO, but this site everyone talks english so I did the translation, anyways thanks for the advice